# MailEnvelope retaining To and BCC information

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using MailEnvelope to email a selected range within a workbook. However, I'm using this multiple times across the workbook (in separate codes) to send different ranges to different recipients etc.

The issue is that if I send one which has To and Bcc recipients, and then I use a different code to send a different range but this is has a To recipient and not the Bcc it is still retaining the Bcc information from the previous code. This is also the same if I have sent with a To and Bcc, and then run another code which is just sending to a Bcc it's retaining the To as well.

Is there a way to clear the sender information each time before the code is run within each code?

```
Sub PrintSaveEmailPdf()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
fpath = "S:\Goods Ordering\Quotes\"
fName = Range("C14").Value & " " & Range("C15").Value & " " & "Week" & " " & 
Range("G10").Value

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fpath & fName, 
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "epc"
Rows("23:33").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Rows("13:13").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

Range("A1:J55").Select


ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
  .Item.To = Range("E21").Value
  .Item.Bcc = Range("G13").Value
  .Introduction = "Please see your quote below from Homesmile - contact 0121-522-4687 
  for any queries"
  .Item.Subject = "Your quote from Homesmile"
  .Item.Send
End With

Rows("22:35").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Rows("12:14").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Range("O17").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveSheet.Protect "epc", True, True

Sheets("Quote").Select
Range("C9").ClearContents
MsgBox "The quote has been emailed"





End Sub
```

Comment: You can try `.Item.Close` after sending the mail.

Comment: I have already tried that and I get "item has been moved or deleted" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim i As Long
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    '~~> Change this to the respective sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:J55")
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = "Charlotte@test.com"
        .CC = "test@test.com"
        .Subject = "Some Subject"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display
    End With
End Sub

'~~> The below is not my code. Also it doesn't need any chnages.
'~~> Keep this as it is
Private Function RangetoHTML(bodyRange As Range) As String
    Dim tempFilePath As String
    tempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With ThisWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=tempFilePath, _
         Sheet:=bodyRange.Parent.Name, _
         Source:=bodyRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With
    
    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim ts As Object
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(tempFilePath).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill tempFilePath

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Function
```

**Edit**: Post discussion in chat. This is how your entire code will look like. (Untested)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim fpath As String, fName As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    fpath = "S:\Goods Ordering\Quotes\"

    '~~> Change this to the respective sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote")

    With ws
        fName = .Range("C14").Value & " " & .Range("C15").Value & " Week " & .Range("G10").Value

        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fpath & fName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

        .Unprotect "epc"
        
        .Rows("23:33").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        .Rows("13:13").EntireRow.Hidden = True

        Set rng = .Range("A1:J55")

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .To = ws.Range("E21").Value
            .BCC = ws.Range("G13").Value
            .Subject = "Your quote from Homesmile"
            .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
            .Display
        End With

        .Rows("22:35").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Rows("12:14").EntireRow.Hidden = False

        .Protect "epc"

        .Range("C9").ClearContents
    End With

    MsgBox "The quote has been emailed"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

'~~> The below is not my code. Also it doesn't need any chnages.
'~~> Keep this as it is
Private Function RangetoHTML(bodyRange As Range) As String
    Dim tempFilePath As String
    tempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With ThisWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add( _
        SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
        Filename:=tempFilePath, _
        Sheet:=bodyRange.Parent.Name, _
        Source:=bodyRange.Address, _
        HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim ts As Object
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(tempFilePath).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)

    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
        "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill tempFilePath

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Yes it is, however I've just tried this code in my worksheet and I'm still having the same issue. Nothing is resetting each time I run it.

Comment: I have tested the code before posting and it works. Are you getting any error?

Comment: No error it runs as it should and the email sends, however previous recipients are still included. I changed the `.Send` to `.Display` so I could check it before sending and there is an email in the To (from another code just run to email) & it should be blank.

Comment: No. Do not do that. It will show you old values. To test it. Put your email address in the `To` and use a fictional email address in `CC`. For example `test@test.com`. Send the email. Check in your inbox if the `To` and `CC` is populated. Then do a 2nd test. this time do not specify `CC`. Send the email. Check the email recieved and you will see that `CC` is blank.

Comment: Still retaining both email addresses. I've literally copied and pasted your code so I'm really confused.

Comment: Ok gimme sometime. I will retest and post it with a screenshot.

Comment: BTW do you need to use `MailEnvelope`? There are better ways to achieve what you want?

Comment: No I don't need to, but it's my go to and I'm not as comfortable with the other options. I'm still very much a beginner.

Comment: I have updated the above post with an alternative method. Test and let me know if it works.? I also have left comments so you should not have a problem understanding it...

Comment: It looks as though this misses out the first part of my code which saves the sheet as a pdf?

Comment: Yes. That can be added later. First test the code that I gave you and see if your main issue is sorted :)

Comment: Ok, I've done that I'm getting **Compile error: Variable not defined** on this line `Set ws = Quote`. I've changed it from Sheet1 to my worksheet name which is Quote.

Comment: Sheet1 in my case was the code name. try `Set ws = Thisworkbook.sheets("Quote")`

Comment: Perfect - that works! I have an image at the top which won't show - is that a setting somewhere? Also - can I change `.Display` to `.Send` so it sends automatically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257150/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-charlotte).